# label, select and button elements on the same line with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How may I put `label`, `select` and `button` elements on the same line?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn m-b" style="float: right">
<!--The below div set the label and button on the same line-->
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
<label style="padding-left:10px; display: inline-block;"for="page">Label Label : </label>
<!--select appears on the new line-->
<select class="form-control post_max m-b" name="page" style="    float: left;">
<option value="">.....</option>    
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: it shows in one line from the code

Comment: I means same line

Comment: Naga Sai A, I'm forgot to add bootstrap library, now I edited the question

Comment: check bootstrap inline-form .. read the doc

Answer (score -1):

Use a container with `display: flex`.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="wrap">
  
  <label for="page">Label: </label>

  <select class="form-control post_max m-b" name="page">
    <option value="">...</option>    
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn m-b">
  
</div>
```

Or alternative, if you don't want to use a custom css, read the documentation about Bootstrap 3 inline forms, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline, use the same snippet you find on that page.

Comment: even if this look correct you need to consider hat he using Bootstrap and bootstrap provide classes to achieve layout ... so no need to force with CSS things we can do by adding simple classes

Comment: thanks aaawww, It's working correctly, but when I change text in label to more than one word, it's divided into new lines  each line contain one word, you can see my question now after edited to understand me thanks.

Comment: @Rawan I can't see your changes in the question above. If I understand your problem, you can try by setting "<select>" element to "flex-basis: 50%;" (or so), this property works in a similar way to the "width" property, google it for more info